# Add View at top of recycler view

Tags: android

In my android application, there is a slideshow at top of page and below it, there is a recycler view, my problem is how to add the slideshow above recycler view in a way that slideshow can be scrolled with recycler view. I tried adding a scroll view as a parent but it seems that recycler lost the recycling power.

```
<RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ececec">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/ChefFragmentViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/ChefFragmentViewPager"
            android:background="#ececec"
            android:scrollbars="none" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your layout xml.

Comment: try using `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`

Comment: @chrjs sorry. edited

Answer (score 0):

Try using `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView` and also set `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` programmatically.

Comment: As I said, like scrollview, it seems recycler lost the recycling power, there will be lags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and let me know if it helped you or not:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ececec">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/ChefFragmentViewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/ChefFragmentViewPager"
                android:background="#ececec"
                android:scrollbars="none" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want view pager scrolls with recycler view too. I don't think your answer can help it.

Comment: They will report you for this I think, but yes, I got it wrong....I'll edit my post now....

Comment: As I said, like scrollview, it seems recycler lost the recycling power, there will be lags.